# What movies does "Hell or High Water" reference?

Tags: reference, hell-or-high-water

What movies does the 2016 film [*Hell or High Water*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_or_High_Water_%28film%29) reference?

Certainly there is a thematic congruence with [*The Wild Bunch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Bunch) regarding men, specifically bank robbers whom history has passed by. The ending is also similar to John Sayles' [*Limbo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_%281999_film%29).

I suspect there are also more direct references, but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Jeff Bridges drives off into the sunset, if you noticed that. =P I actually noticed a few, but I've forgotten now what they were.

Comment: It was a badass ending. I was like "oh no you're not!" and then they did. Awesome. :)

Comment: Right? And then, I'm all "Why are we watching him walk to his car?" and "Aw, crap, he's gonna ride off into the sunset!"

Comment: To me, it seemed like a watered down version of No Country for Old Men.

Comment: @BoltBait You need to go back and re-watch the films of Sam Peckinpah, particularly the Westerns (Wild Bunch, Bring Me The Head of Alfredo Garcia, etc.)  No Country was based on a literary novel by Cormac McCarthy, which is why it is so elevated.  But Hell or High Water is actually a deeper commentary on themes particular to the Western genre, specifically in cinema.  (Shane, the films of [John Ford](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000406/?ref_=tt_ov_dr#director), etc.)  No Country is concerned with the perception of violence at a given point in history (i.e. present times vs. grandfather's times)

Comment: Or this movie is just a neowestern referencing the western genre as a whole.